# Card animation elements not properly aligned

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to create a card similar to sample card but my card is not proper. I have provided photos and code of my card and also what I want it to look like.

**My card at the moment:**

| No hover | Hover |
| --- | --- |
| [image: before hovering] | [image: image after hovering] |

**What I want it to look like:**

| No hover | Hover |
| --- | --- |
| [image: before hovering] | [image: image after hovering] |

Below is the HTML and CSS code files of my card. the issue I am facing is the text appearing after hovering is not in proper box. Also if you want you can make it better.

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    background: whitesmoke;
}
.card{
   height: 500px; 
   margin: 50px;
   box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px black;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
img{
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: .5s;
}
.intro{
    height: 200px;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 6px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    /* background: rgb(27,27,27,.5); */
    color: white;
    bottom: 99px;
    transition: .5s;
}
h1{
   margin: 20px;
   font-size: 40px; 
}
p{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.card:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.card:hover .intro{
    height: 220px;
    bottom: 240px;
    /* background: black; */
}
.card:hover p{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.card:hover img{
    transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-3deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sty.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="puppy.jpeg" alt="">
            <div class="intro">
                <h1>helloo ji</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat est quisquam quo omnis dolores, ipsa, blanditiis assumenda eius tempore temporibus ipsum earum deserunt, ut facilis optio! Eveniet ad unde fugiat!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close to the solution, however there are a few small issues with your approach:

- the text doesn't appear in the card on hover, which is probably because you're using pixel heights which can quickly get out of hand.
- there isn't room to change the text if you choose to update your website's contents - that's due to these measurements too.

If we take another look at how we do the measurements and animations for the hover effect, we can remove pixel measurements for the `height`, and we can remove how the `bottom` property affects where the text is.

We can also use the `transform` property to move the text up 100% of that element's height - without having to guess a `bottom` position.

Here is the updated code, with comments so you can see what I've done:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    background: whitesmoke;
}
.card{
   height: 500px; 
   margin: 50px;
   box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px black;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
img{
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: .5s;
}
.intro {
    /* Auto height is what we're looking for, so get rid of the following line: */
    /* height: 200px; */
    width: 350px;
    padding: 6px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    /* background: rgb(27,27,27,.5); */
    color: white;
    /* Don't need this any more: */
    /* bottom: 99px; */
    transition: all .5s;
}
/* Separate element for the title - we position it so it can be
seen on the card, when it would otherwise overflow */
.title {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 20px - 20px));
    transition: transform .5s;
}
/* Then don't do that on hover */
.card:hover .title {
    transform: translateY(0);
}
h1{
   /* changed margin to make it look nicer */
   margin: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   font-size: 40px; 
}
p{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.card:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.card:hover .intro{
    /* height: 220px; */
    /* no `bottom` needed */
    transform: translateY(-100%); /* Move it up 100% of its height */
    /* background: black; */
}
.card:hover p{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.card:hover img{
    transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-3deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sty.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557374800-8ba4ccd60e9d?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3716&q=80" alt="">
            <div class="intro">
                <h1 class="title">helloo ji</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat est quisquam quo omnis dolores, ipsa, blanditiis assumenda eius tempore temporibus ipsum earum deserunt, ut facilis optio! Eveniet ad unde fugiat!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <!-- more stuff can go here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To fix the issue you raised in comments about the heading not being there, you should first add a class to your heading element, and then make it have a negative transform. You might need to play around with the way transitions work to make sure the hover effect is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. but I want the Heading to be present on Card and when I hover the text will appear. your solution is correct but the heading is not present on card initially.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that, I'll edit my answer

Comment: I believe I've fixed the issue @ashish and hope this is now what you're looking for

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for resolving this issue also I will learn how transitions work.

Comment: you should have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_transitions/Using_CSS_transitions if you're interested

Answer (score 0):

Change the bottom size in `.card:hover .intro` to a larger value. E.g.: `bottom: 300px;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.card {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 50px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px black;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

img {
  height: 500px;
  width: 350px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.intro {
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  /* background: rgb(27,27,27,.5); */
  color: white;
  bottom: 99px;
  transition: .5s;
}

h1 {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.card:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card:hover .intro {
  height: 220px;
  bottom: 300px;
  /* background: black; */
}

.card:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.card:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-3deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="puppy.jpeg" alt="">
    <div class="intro">
      <h1>helloo ji</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat est quisquam quo omnis dolores, ipsa, blanditiis assumenda eius tempore temporibus ipsum earum deserunt, ut facilis optio! Eveniet ad unde fugiat!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```